# android intent to navigate to multiple destinations?

Tags: android, navigation, android-intent

is there any way to navigate to multiple destinations? like you can do on google maps?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what your are trying to achieve, and how you're trying to achieve it?

Comment: sorry :) what I'm trying to achieve is navigate from point A to point B then C then D like in this google map i've set up http://bit.ly/dkwSnd but the adresses would chosen by the user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably know you can use the following, undocumented, way to navigate to a destination

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude)));
```

but, as far as I know, navigation with intermediate points is not possible at the moment.

Comment: sucks :( but then is it maybe possible to get a callback when the user has reached his reached his destination?

Comment: You could try using startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity(), but I haven't tried it and I'm not sure that it works.

Comment: are mLatitude and mLongitude decimal degrees or interger microdegrees?

Answer (score 1):

There are no documented and supported `Intents` for use with Google Navigation, sorry.