# Showing multiple address on map with mark

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am confused with 1 thing related with maps that:

There are 2 ways we can use to show address on map:

- 1) Using native/built in map application and use the following code to show address on map with marker on it:

  ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW , 
          Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q= (" + MyAddress+ ")"));
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

Here It automatically convert the latitude and longitude and open the native maps application and show that address on map.

- 2) Here we have to use map view in our own application and show map.
  But here I am confused with that Is there any way that we can show multiple address on map using (1) method??

Because here I am passing only 1 address i.e. `MyAddress` but what will be the way to pass multiple address?
 Is this possible or not?

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292508/default-google-map-with-multiple-lat-long-using-geo-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I Know, in Android **currently not supported** multiple address markup in native Google Map application **via Intent**. You can show only one address using Intent in native Google Map application. For multiple addresses on map you have to build your own android map application.

Comment: Look at [How to use built-in google map application to display many place markers based on data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816561/android-intent-to-navigate-to-multiple-destinations)