# Default google map with multiple lat long using geo in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using following code to display location on default google map using **geo**

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"?q="+Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"");
 Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(in);
```

Its working fine. Now i wanna know that, can i display multiple locations (multiple lat,long) on default map using geo? can i pass array or anything else?

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, for that you need to have SDK which comes for displaying multiple marks at Google Maps in Android and you can download that SDK from here.  [SDK](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

And here you can find complete guide on [HOW TO SHOW MORE THAN ONE MARKS IN ANDROID GOOGLE MAP](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-mall-finder-app-points-of-interest/)

In below class array has been passed for different location

```
public void drawMalls(){
Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.malls);
MallOverlay mallsPos = new MallOverlay(marker,mapView);
    GeoPoint[] mallCoords = new GeoPoint[6];

    //Load Some Random Coordinates in Miami, FL
    mallCoords[0] = new GeoPoint(29656582,-82411151);//The Oaks Mall
    mallCoords[1] = new GeoPoint(29649831,-82376347);//Creekside mall
    mallCoords[2] = new GeoPoint(29674146,-8238905);//Millhopper Shopping Center
    mallCoords[3] = new GeoPoint(29675078,-82322617);//Northside Shopping Center
    mallCoords[4] = new GeoPoint(29677017,-82339761);//Gainesville Mall
    mallCoords[5] = new GeoPoint(29663835,-82325599);//Gainesville Shopping Center      

    List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[0], "The Oaks Mall", "6419 W Newberry Rd, Gainesville, FL 32605");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[1], "Creekside Mall", "3501 Southwest 2nd Avenue, Gainesville, FL");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[2], "Millhopper Shopping Center", "NW 43rd St & NW 16th Blvd. Gainesville, FL");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[3], "Northside Shopping Center", "Gainesville, FL");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[4], "Gainesville Mall", "2624 Northwest 13th Street Gainesville, FL 32609-2834");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlayItem = new OverlayItem(mallCoords[5], "Gainesville Shopping Center", "1344 N Main St Gainesville, Florida 32601");
mallsPos.addOverlay(overlayItem);
overlays.add(mallsPos); 

mallsPos.setCurrentLocation(currentLocation);
```

}

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But i need to create mapview layout for it. I want to do on default google map using uri

Comment: see my above code i haven't use mapview in it. I'm using geo uri to display location on google map. So is it possible to show different locations using uri of geo?

Comment: Hmm..Thanks for mapview this is gud solution